Separate repository for Swift Package Manager users
Currently, in order to resolve MerketingCloudSDK dependency using Swift Package manager, we have to download the whole repository and the size is around 1.5-2 Gigabytes, which is huge and drastically slows down the whole dependency resolution step (especially after cleaning caches and DerivedData in Xcode). Unfortunately, this is how Swift Package Manager works, it always downloads the whole repository, but there are some good ideas to optimise it. I can give an example with Lottie: they created a separate repo for SPM users so it contains only URLs to the binaries (XCFrameworks) and is now super lightweight. https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-spm/blob/main/Package.swift
Is there any plan to create something similar for MarketingCloudSDK? Every new release of the SDK adds 30-50 MB to the repo and in a year or two the size of the repo will become 2 times larger.
